# Increasing size of video thumbnail on mouseover

Tags: javascript, optimization, performance, video

This is a user JavaScript for YouTube. The point is to make the thumbnail bigger on mouseover. I just want some help making it better because I don't want it to waste resources with all the extensions I have and other scrips. I also added Iframes because I have another extension that makes a preview of the video in the thumbnail. I also use Opera so make sure it works on Opera.

```
/*! settings begin */
//Makes the name of the video apear bellow the image if false (false/true)
var WideSideBar = true;
/*! settings end */

//Get the sidebar were the thumbnails are and the main
var videos = document.getElementById("watch7-sidebar");
var main = document.getElementById("watch7-main");
//Make the SideBar wider
if (WideSideBar) {
    main.style.width = "1117px";
    videos.style.width = "472px";
}

videos.addEventListener("mouseover", function (a) {
    if (a.target.tagName == "IMG") {
        //Make image bigger
        a.target.style.width = "292px";
        a.target.style.height = "163px";
        a.target.style.WebkitTransition = 'width 0.5s, height 0.5s';
        a.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.width = "292px";
        a.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.height = "163px";
        a.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.WebkitTransition = 'width 0.5s, height 0.5s';

        //Get a higher resolution image of the thumbnail
        var video_id = a.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.href.split('v=')[1];
        var ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');
        if (ampersandPosition != -1) {
            video_id = video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
        }
        a.target.src = "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + video_id + "/0.jpg";

    } else if (a.target.tagName == "IFRAME") {

        //Make Iframe AKA:(Thumbnail preview) bigger
        a.target.parentNode.style.WebkitTransition = 'width 0.5s, height 0.5s';
        a.target.parentNode.style.width = "292px";
        a.target.parentNode.style.height = "163px";
    }
}, false);

videos.addEventListener("mouseout", function (a) {
    if (a.target.tagName == "IMG") {

        //Make image normal size.
        a.target.style.width = "120px";
        a.target.style.height = "67px";
        a.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.width = "120px";
        a.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.height = "67px";
    } else if (a.target.tagName == "IFRAME") {
        //Make Iframe AKA:(Thumbnail preview) normal size
        a.target.parentNode.style.width = "120px";
        a.target.parentNode.style.height = "67px";
    }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the :hover pseudo class and have that trigger the size change? Probably easier than having to worry about event binding.
http://jsfiddle.net/nhzNM/

```
<iframe class="videoPlayer" width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/90Omh7_I8vI?controls=0&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<style type="text/css">
.videoPlayer {
    width: 560px;
    height: 315px;
    -webkit-transition: height,width 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: height,width 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: height,width 1s ease;
    -o-transition: height,width 1s ease;
    transition: height,width 1s ease;
}

.videoPlayer:hover {
    width: 650px;
    height: 365px;
}
</style>
```

You could use the same setup for a thumbnail positioned in front of the video embed.

Comment: One of the problems is that in youtube I have to change the width and the height of another element so it works.
    a.target.style.height = "163px";  
    a.target.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.style.height = "163px";

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in your code that should cause any performance issues.  You're not doing anything iterative, or performing any complex operations; your code just executes linearly and changes some CSS properties.  That shouldn't kill performance.

Have you seen anything to indicate that this code *does* kill performance?  If so then the only thing I could suggest is changing the events that you listen for (or maybe, adding some logic to ensure that you don't start a new transition while the current one is still running), as perhaps the page is triggering more `mouseover` and `mouseout` events than you expect.

Premature optimization is the root of all evil, and all that.

Also, you should be able to do:

```
    video_id = video_id.split('&')[0];  //this works whether or not an `&` is present
```

...instead of:

```
    var ampersandPosition = video_id.indexOf('&');
    if (ampersandPosition != -1) {
        video_id = video_id.substring(0, ampersandPosition);
    }
```

That (probably) won't perform any better, but it's less code to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need IE9+ support, you can use the `transform: scale` property in CSS, and avoid JavaScript altogether:

```css
img {
  transition: all .2s;
  margin: 50px;
}

img:hover {
  -ms-transform: scale(1.2); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.2) /* Safari, iOS, Android */
  transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempizza.com/380/240">
```

IE10 users will not enjoy the transition, but will still see the scale.